# как добавить множество в массив

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

мне нужно получить массив вида ф[set{ftdecjhe}, set{dgfyie}, set{fgwra}]
чтобы потом взять пересечение всех множеств через распаковку
так вот
как получить подобное

Answer (score 1):

если я правильно понял условие:

```
s1 = set('ftdecjhe')
s2 = set('dgfyie')
s3 = set('fgwra')
res = set.intersection(*[s1, s2, s3])

print(res)
#{'f'}
```